# Fetched data from firebase is not showing on alertDialog

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the data(faculty members name) from firebase. The fetched data is not showing on the dialog but it is showing on the toast.

Here is the code:

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FacultyMember");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            String Name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
            list.add(Name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminHome.this);
builder.setTitle("Member List");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp);
builder.setItems(list.toArray(new String[0]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
    {

    }
});
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of that `reference.addValueEventListener` is triggered after alertDialog has been created. because the `addValueEventListener` is only triggered after an `addValueEvent` has been occured, so in your code the empty list has been passed to your alertDialog and then showing, after that the data has been fetch and `reference.addValueEventListener` has been triggered. you must create alertDialog after all your data has been fetch, not sooner.

for example, you must know number of your results and count the fetched data in `onDataChange` method, and just show the alertDialog when number of fetchData reach to excepted count.

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
int execptedResult = NUMBER_OF_RESULT; // <--- you must fetch data from firebase in some way, it depends on your implementation 
int fetchCount = 0;
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FacultyMember");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            fetchCount++;
            String Name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
            list.add(Name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(fetchCount == execptedResult){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminHome.this);
                builder.setTitle("Member List");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp);
                builder.setItems(list.toArray(new String[0]), new 
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                        {

                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try by replacing this

```
builder.setItems(list.toArray(new String[0]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

using

```
builder.setItems(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener())
```